# Create letters similar to old ones

Tags: fonts

Alert: Amateur asking a question!

I've got a job where I have to make copies of old letters that are engraved in on headstones.

Often these letters are old and don't exist in any font Library. What is the most suitable software for copying the existing letters (from a picture), and create new letters that look the same?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Any chance you could post an image or example?  Chances are there might be a font that's similar enough, and might only need tweaking. It's hard to answer this without seeing anything!  Also do you need a whole font that you can use to type with?  Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/152458/edit) and add more details. Thanks.

Comment: This is not about headstone engravings, but there one tells how he created a font which replicated acceptable texts in a handwritten book. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/146958/recreating-old-handwriting-into-a-font